# Windows Phone 7 emulator support any GPS device for development

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, emulation

I am developing for Windows Phone 7.

My application uses GeoCoordinateWatcher to detect user current position.

Now my client is asking me to test GPS functionality. But i don't have Windows Phone 7 mobile available here. I want to connect a GPS receiver with my laptop and somehow connect that to Windows Phone 7 emulator so the emulator would receive the data from my USB GPS receiver.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Kevin D. Wolf's [GPS simulator](http://new.efficientcoder.net/2010/09/gps-simulator-for-windows-phone-7.html) for Windows Phone 7.

It will allow you to test the GPS fonctionality of your app without any GPS device.